# Websocket is not connecting with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

So i'm trying to connect to a websocket server using javascript. I tried doing this with NODEJS with the following code and it worked.

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('<Websocket Address>', {
  origin: '<URL>'
});

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({"event":"auth","args":["<My authentication token>"]}))
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({"event":"send logs","args":[null]}))
  console.log('connected');
});

ws.on('close', function close() {
  console.log('disconnected');
});
ws.addEventListener('send logs', function (event) {
  console.log('Message from server ', event);
});
ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(data);
  
  }, 500);
```

Is there a way I can write this in plain javascript? Like in script tags? I've read that the following code should work but it's giving me this error Uncaught DOMException: "An invalid or illegal string was specified"

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('<Websocket address>', {
  origin: '<URL>'
});

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({"event":"auth","args":["<My authentication Token>"]}))
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({"event":"send logs","args":[null]}))
  console.log('connected');
});

ws.on('close', function close() {
  console.log('disconnected');
});
ws.addEventListener('send logs', function (event) {
  console.log('Message from server ', event);
});
ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(data);
  
  }, 500);
```

Could anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exact line is the error on when you try to put it in a web page?  And, are you putting this Javascript in a script tag?

Comment: Also, are you aware that the webSocket interface built into the browser is not exactly the same as  the module you're using in nodejs?